# Clarification on Answerswarm winners

Tags: discussion, answer-swarm

So just a clarification, when you say:

"Awarding prizes for the Leagues: Up to 150 people who complete the Gold League will win a t-shirt." and "25% of the people entered into each raffle will be selected."

If the league only had 35 qualified winners, then you'll just get 25% of them(9 people). Is that correct? And the up to 150 limit is only for let's say there were 700 qualified people, only 150 will be awarded and not 175?

Comment: That is exactly how I would interpret it.  Although somebody mentioned they'd round down and not up, so 8 of 35.

Comment: interesting thought, if there was only 1 eligible guy, then 25% of that rounded down would be 0...?

Comment: that doesn't seem right, but we will see, since there was only one master level winner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clarifying how winners are picked for the Answer Swarm prizes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/clarifying-how-winners-are-picked-for-the-answer-swarm-prizes)

Comment: @Michel I didn't ask this question there :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep! The Gold League maxes out at 150 winners no matter what. Everything else maxes out at 25% of total entries.

Comment: by 'no matter what' you mean for gold league, there will be 150 winners so if it's less than that, then everyone gets it?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. Should that change, I will make a public announcement to that effect. :)

Comment: sweeeet! :) thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/diablo-3-acts-rule-changeeveryone-gets-a-t-shirt?rq=1